# One shot webtoon about an orphan female lead adopted by a duke's family who ends up being a lost princess

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics, medieval

The child female lead (FL) (blonde and blue eyes) is the daughter of a concubine but grows up in a couple of different orphanages because of the empress. The emperor was off to war when the FL was born, so when the concubine died and the child went missing, he was told it was a boy. He looks for the child but eventually gives up. The FL found out she was the child and went to meet the emperor who didn’t believe her because the empress took her power to give to her daughter that is not the emperors child. The emperor then forced the FL into some kind of prison mirror.

After this, it cuts to the FL (either experiencing a time regression or an isekai knowing the plot of the “novel”). The FL gets adopted by a ducal family that dotes on her and she equally loves them. (Same ducal family was in the novel where the empress daughter spread a plague on their land and the duke takes responsibility for allowing the same plague spread and offers his head. The empress daughter used the FL's stolen power to heal the plague she released to solidify her position as the princess.)

Eventually, the ducal family gets robbed and the FL wanting to protect her family ends up awakening her power and getting it back in full. The emperor, who still is searching for his lost son, realizes that a new power has awakened when he still believes is his son goes looking finds the FL in a candy shop realizes he actually had a daughter but soon finds out she was adopted by duke family. The emperor is sad but eventually goes home to his son to tell him he found his sibling. The son was mad that the emperor didn’t bring her home.

The emperor then goes to duke's house bringing candy to bribe her daughter into going home with him, but gets denied as the daughter doesn’t like candy and loves the duke's family. The emperor is sad again. The emperor and duke team up against the empress. The FL gets both imperial and duke's last name. The FL goes to the palace and meets the empress daughter who says something like the FL took affection that belonged to her or something.

I can’t remember anything else

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?

Comment: This has a lot of plot elements - are you certain it was a oneshot?